# How to align similar lines of code using whitespace in Netbeans/MPLab X?

Tags: netbeans, code-formatting, mplab

Is there an existing macro or plugin which will turn this

```
Config.MyData1 = Data++;
Config.MyData10 = Data++;
Config.MyData100 = Data++;
Config.MyData1000 = Data++;
```

into this?

```
Config.MyData1    = *Data++;
Config.MyData10   = *Data++;
Config.MyData100  = *Data++;
Config.MyData1000 = *Data++;
```

Using Delphi with GExpert I used to use "Align Line" (ctrl+alt+z). Is there a similar tool for Netbeans/MPLAB-X?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any similar function in MPLABX. But you may try putting a tab character before the '=' using the replace function.

First, write a tabulation using tab key, and copy this.
Then press 'CTRL+H' and replace all the requires '=' by '  ='.

*(The wait space is a tab, it seems to be that it doesn't support writing \t for a tab).*

Regards